# How to edit the current buffer in another existing buffer?

Tags: vimscript

As title. I'm in a situation where a file is loaded into a buffer that is not listed in the buffers from the list `:ls`. So I want to transfer the content of the current unlisted buffer to an existing buffer(supposed to be a `[No Name]`).

Or put it simple: Is it possible to make an unlisted buffer get listed?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Does `:set buflisted` resolve your issue? See [`:help 'buflisted'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27buflisted%27). How come you're getting an unlisted buffer? And what is not working because the buffer is unlisted, are you having trouble saving the file or something like that? What error do you get when you try such an operation?

Comment: @filbranden: Thanks for your good questions. I think the first one solves my question. I will answer myself later if appropriate, or delete it if not. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and post a self-answer if that answered your question! If you'd like to also [edit] your question to make it clearer what the issue you were having was (trouble saving?), that would be excellent. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I'm not sure what the screenshot has to do with anything: if you want readers to look at code, [please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Sorry my bad. I was trying to demo the there are two `[No Name]` at the above and both were not selected. So the content of the current buffer is actually not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is more complex than what I described in the OP. But, in short, if you have the information that your current file content is loaded in a buffer that is not listed (by not listed I meant those buffers which won't shown by `:ls`) Then some ways to "stage" it can be:

1. `edit`
2. `set buflisted` (I take this approach)

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', ';', function ()
  if vim.bo.filetype ~= 'neo-tree' then
    vim.cmd('NeoNoNameClean')
  end
  vim.cmd('Neotree float toggle reveal_force_cwd dir=' .. vim.fn.getcwd())
  if vim.bo.filetype ~= 'neo-tree'
    and not vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(0, 'buflisted') then
      vim.cmd('set buflisted')
  end
end, NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
```

Comment: Welcome to Vim. You should not use the answer section to precise your question. It will confuse the future readers. Could you please instead edit your original question?